# array sorting on element

Tags: php

I have this array and I want to sort it on name

```
Array
(
    [id] => 12
    [name] => Henry Davidson
    [modified] => 2011-03-14 21:48:59
    [modified_by] => James H 
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$names = array();
foreach ( $your_array as $key => $value )
{
    $names[$key] = $value['name'];
}
array_multisort($names, SORT_ASC, $your_array);
```

Comment: Glad to hear it works for you. Will you post your modifications for the benefit of others who may need it in the future?

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use uasort. (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) with your own callback function for sorting on the field you wish to sort on. Usually for things such as a name, you can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php

Directly from the example on the uasort page:

```
<?php
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a["fruit"], $b["fruit"]);
}

$fruits[0]["fruit"] = "lemons";
$fruits[1]["fruit"] = "apples";
$fruits[2]["fruit"] = "grapes";

usort($fruits, "cmp");

while (list($key, $value) = each($fruits)) {
    echo "\$fruits[$key]: " . $value["fruit"] . "\n";
}
```

?>

Answer (score 1):

Sorts by last name. You may have to make some changes if there is more or less than a first and last name.

```
function sort_by_name($a, $b)
{
    $a = explode(' ', $a['name']);
    $b = explode(' ', $b['name']);
    if($a[1] == $b[1])
    {
        return strcmp($a[0], $b[0]);
    }
    return strcmp($a[1], $b[1]);
}

usort($array, 'sort_by_name');
```